# How to pipe background processes in a shell script

Tags: shell, pipe, background-process

I have a Shell script that starts a few background processes (using `&`) and are automatically killed when the user calls Ctrl+C (using `trap`). This works well:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

trap "exit" INT TERM ERR
trap "kill 0" EXIT

command1 &
command2 &
command3 &

wait
```

Now I would like to filter the output of command3 with a `grep -v "127.0.0.1"` to exclude all the line with `127.0.0.1`. Like this:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

trap "exit" INT TERM ERR
trap "kill 0" EXIT

command1 &
command2 &
command3 | grep -v "127.0.0.1" & 

wait
```

The problem is that the signal Ctrl+C doesn't kill command3 anymore.

Is there a way to capture pipe `command3` with the `grep` in order to be able to kill at the end of the process?

Thanks

Comment: Try (command3 | grep -v "127.0.0.1") &

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will answer my own question. The problem was in the trap too limited. I changed to kill all `jobs` properly.

```sh
#!/bin/sh

killjobs() {
    for job in $(jobs -p); do
        kill -s SIGTERM $job > /dev/null 2>&1 || (sleep 10 && kill -9 $job > /dev/null 2>&1 &)
    done
}
trap killjobs EXIT

command1 &
command2 &
command3 | grep -v "127.0.0.1" & 

wait
```